# how to view a picture in a word document on offline mode VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, contentdocument

I trying to access a picture in offline mode ( without a connection), stored in a word document which i generated with visualforce but it gives the following error.

[image: e]

Can you please, tell me if it is possible to display an image enven in offline mode?
Thank you so much.